Can DataCloud be linked to external systems and analyze those data together with SF Data?
Question - can you link DataCloud to external Systems like Hubspot, LinkedIn, Salesloft or any other system in order to analyze it using DataCloud and even combine it with Salesforce Data to get real deep Data analysis and understanding?
Reason: we have SF and many external systems linked to it. We want to analyse Big Data from different sources and considering using DataCloud for that.
If you can share your experiences would be appreciated.
Thank you very much!
Sincerely,
